# Intel 8080: How to MOV DE to B?

Tags: assembly, intel, intel-8080

I used `LXI D` and `LXI H` to load immediate register pairs `DE` and `HL`.
When I use `MOV A, M` it works for `HL` value to move into `A`, but how to move `DE` to `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use instruction `A1` — `LDAX D` in Intel speak and `LD A, (DE)` in Zilog speak — then do a quick `47` — `MOV A, B` / `LD B, A`.

There's no instruction to load directly to B from indirect DE.